# Parse JSON from Domino agent

Tags: java, lotus-domino

In a Domino agent I am reading messages from a messaging service. The message is in JSON format. Is there any approach to parse easily the JSON? The purpose is to create Notes documents from the messages.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too broad what is the json and what have you tried

just a small eg

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

String json = "{ \"f1\":\"Hello\",\"f2\":{\"f3:\":\"World\"}}";

JsonElement jsonTree = parser.parse(json);

if(jsonTree.isJsonObject()){
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonTree.getAsJsonObject();

    JsonElement f1 = jsonObject.get("f1");

    JsonElement f2 = jsonObject.get("f1");

    if(f2.isJsonObject()){
        JsonObject f2Obj = f2.getAsJsonObject();

        JsonElement f3 = f2Obj.get("f3");
    }

}
```

Comment: I have not tried anything yet, I am just orientating what my options are. I do not care how my json looks like it. I just receive it as a string and I would like to parse it, validate it and finally create Notes documents from it.

Comment: where is the JsonParser coming from?

Comment: I am working with a Domino agent here  so I can not use the http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonParser ?

Comment: You need to use gson parser or jackon to parse json valuez